# Loading Coordinates without shp file but prj, cpg, hdf, xml

Tags: google-earth-engine, import, modis, hdf, prj

I want to import the grids for pixel tiles of a MODIS data set and received the data for that from someone else. However, it does not contain a .shp file but only .prj, .cpg., .hdf and .xml.

Is there a way to illustrate those tiles with the data I have?

In the end I need to import them into Google Earth Engine but if there's a way to load it in ArcGIS Pro or QGIS, it already helps a lot!

If it is not possible to load the grid like that, what further information would be needed?

Comment: Did you try to load the HDF files in QGIS or ArcGIS Pro, or directly into Google EE?

Comment: Google Earth Engine definitely will not accept an upload without a `.shp` file — it expects features, not only projection information. However, I imagine it might be possible to _create_ a `.shp` which contains a regular grid of points, or rectangles, which will then be interpreted in the projection data you already have. But I am not familiar with the details of the shapefile format, so I don't know how practical this is.